# Outer measure exclusion of zero set

Tags: self-learning, lebesgue-measure

I've just started self-studying measure theory by reading Pugh's Mathematical Analysis. He shows that the exclusion of a zero set does not change the outer measure: $m^*(E\setminus Z)=m^*(E)$, but there is a small thing I'm not understanding in his argument:

Let $Z$ be a zero set, $E\subseteq\mathbb{R}$, and $m^*$ be the Lebesgue outer measure. Since $m^*(E)=m^*(E\cup Z)$, applying this to the set $E\setminus Z$ gives **$m^*(E\setminus Z)=m^*((E\setminus Z)\cup(E\cap Z))=m^*(E).$**

My question is where does the $E\cap Z$ come from in the second equality? If you're using $m^*(E)=m^*(E\cup Z)$ applied to $E\setminus Z$, why isn't it $m^*(E\setminus Z)=m^*((E\setminus Z)\cup Z)?$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$(E\setminus Z)\cup(E\cap Z)=E$, so the equation in the second paragraph is just the one in the first paragraph with $m^*(E)$ rewritten.

Comment: Yes, I understand that $(E\setminus Z)\cup (E\cap Z)=E$, but I don't understand why, if we make the substitution $E\to E\setminus Z$, we go from $m^*(E)=m^*(E\cup Z)$ to $m^*(E\setminus Z)=m^*((E\setminus Z)\cup (E\cap Z))$ instead of just $m^*(E\setminus Z)=m^*((E\setminus Z)\cup Z)$